# Strapi.io graphQL mutation

Tags: graphql, crud, strapi

In strapi, we're able to build the client query which is perfect. However, i can't see any documentation on mutation/update of record using graphql.

Is this a custom implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GraphQL mutations have been developed and merged: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/pull/1650. They will be published in the next release.